Showing nothing in solaar software in ubuntu 24.04
I attached the image, where it is not showing anything, and there is no option for pairing devices also what can i do?

Sorry this is not a question. A question needs to be more then a link. Please read the info on this link and edit the question with some details. https://askubuntu.com/help/how-to-ask
